# Estoy colocando un asteroide pero no se comporta correctamente en unity

Tags: unity3d, unity, unity2d

Hola estoy realizando un juego de naves y coloque un meteorito pero cuando lo ejecuto se va hacia un lado o hacia arriba y necesito que baje el meteorito hacia mi personaje principal este es mi codigo.

```
{
    public float Velocidad = 6;
    Rigidbody rb;

   
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        rb.velocity = Vector3.back * Velocidad + Vector3.right * Random.Range(-1, 1);
        rb.angularVelocity = new Vector3 (Random.Range(-5, 5), Random.Range(-5, 5), Random.Range(-5, 5));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que comprobar la posición del jugador en cada frame, por eso solo la comprueba una vez al inicio(void Start()) y luego se va directo en ese lugar.

Te que uses recomiendo que sea el método que revisa cada vez que un frame se actualiza para que no sea un jet en vez de un meteorito jajaja

Comment: disculpa la demora pero si correctamente es eso.

Comment: @EduardoOrtiz tranquilo igual disculpa tu por no responderte mucho antes y ser de ayuda igual puedes colocarla como al solución, para quienes tengan un problema similar